# Why is else statement a infinite loop?

Tags: java, loops, infinite-loop

I am fairly new to Java and I am trying to work on my data validation. The code runs fine when I use valid data, but when I put in a string instead of an integer the code just loops forever. It just loops the, "Bad input. Please enter a number." Thanks in advance!

```
    //Get input from user
    System.out.print("What is your name (Last, First)? ");
    String name = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.print("enter a date:");
    String datein = scan.nextLine();

    boolean valid = false;
    while (valid != true)
    {   
        System.out.print("Electricity used (KW):");
        if (scan.hasNextDouble())
        {
            electricityUsed = scan.nextDouble();
            valid = true;
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Bad input. Please enter a number.");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix it add a `scan.nextLine()` to your else branch.

Answer (score 8):

because `hasNextDouble` always returns false.

here is the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextDouble%28%29).  You answer your own question :

> but when I put in a string instead of an integer

Comment: +1 If you type anything but a double, it will keep finding that it is not a double, and never consume it.  Add `scan.nextLine();` to the `else` block.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. the scan.nextLine(); fixed the problem. Thank you for the link above about hasNextDouble.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler approach is to use the following.

```
System.out.print("Electricity used (KW):");
while(!scan.hasNextDouble()) {
    scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Bad input. Please enter a number.");
    System.out.print("Electricity used (KW):");
}
double electricityUsed = scan.nextDouble();
```